# Android DatePicker does not scroll beyond 2100 year

Tags: android, datepicker

I just observed that the DatePicker year does not scroll beyond 2100 year. Not sure why is there a limit on the year. How can I set no limit on the year while scrolling?

Comment: This is default end year. Use `setMaxDate(long)` in code or use `android:maxDate` XML attribute to change it.

Answer (score 0):

'Pawel' comment is correct.

This is sample code for setMaxDate.

replace return new DatePickerDialog(this, pDateSetListener, pYear, pMonth, pDay) statement with something like this:

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, listener, year, month, day);
dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
return dialog;
```

date picker example :

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    findViewById(R.id.btn_date_picker_dialog).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(PickerActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int date) { 
                    //TODO Do something
                }
            }, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DATE));

            dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());    //Option not to click after date entered
            dialog.show();

        }
    });
```